# Sad face with x for eyes in ChromeOS Kiosk

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-os

From time to time I randomly get this on two ChromeBits in Kiosk mode with Google Sign Builder running. They normally show a Google Sheets with a graphic in it.

The devices are plugged into a TV in a factory, without keyboard or mouse, and is way out of reach. But they are registered on Google Admin so I can get logs and screenshots from behind, but other than the screenshot below, I can't find anything useful and a google search on this exact image did not yield anything either. I found similar pictures of a sad face but not this exact one.

Any clue what that means exactly?

[image: Sad face with X for eyes on ChromeOS]

<sup>Cropped to relevant area, click through for full size</sup>

P.-S.: I have another identical setup but with a Google Slide displayed and this one has been running fine 24/7 for months.

Comment: I've ended up replacing the Google Sheet document by a Google Presentation with the Sheets chart embedded into it. My two ChromeBits have been running fine since then (two years). Solid devices. It's a shame they're discontinued.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what it means *vaguely* – it's a ripoff of the [Sad Mac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh_startup#Sad_Mac) screen that old Macintosh computers used to have if the system failed to boot. The Chrome browser uses [a similar design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWD7R.png) whenever a tab (render process) or a browser plugin crashes or is killed.

This particular rectangle shape [used to be](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=617926) used for dead plugins, including e.g. the PDF viewer and PNaCl apps. (Now the plugins have a "sad plugin" graphic instead.)

So within Chrome OS, this icon most likely means that the app or rendering engine it uses crashed for any reason. (E.g. maybe the system ran out of RAM and killed the heaviest process it could find?) Unfortunately Chrome OS doesn't seem to have a global "code search" tool like the Chromium project has, so I couldn't find the exact conditions, but I also don't think there are any.

Comment: I'm sorry in the question I said the Google Sign app displayed a Google Slide while in fact it is a Google Sheets with a graphic in it, and it is updated frequently. And by the way I have two setups like this one and they both crash the same way. Also, after a while, the Sheets page comes back on. Could be the browser refreshing or the device rebooting, hard to say since there is no task bar. I'll update the question.